# How do you assign roles with the discord.py rewrite?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am creating a discord bot using `discord.py` rewrite and am hosting iton repl.it. I am trying to add assignment of roles, but I get an error everytime I try to add it

I'be looked around stack overflow and have been unable to find a solution to adding roles. I've also looked through the documentation, but that just made me more confused.

```py
import discord.utils 
@client.command()
async def role(ctx, * role):
  user = ctx.message.author
  role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name=f"{role}")
  await ctx.add_roles(user, role)
```

It should add the specified role to the message author but it just produces this error

```
File "main.py", line 18, in role
    await ctx.add_roles(user, role)
AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'add_roles'
```

Comment: It's not `server` it's `guild` https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.guild

Comment: Thanks @AlbertoPoljak. After Updating that I get a new error. I updated the post with that.

Comment: You have to use it on member example `await user.add_roles(role)`

Comment: Also for role you better use converter, so instead of `* role` use `role: discord.Role` which can take role by id, name, or mention. It will automatically give you the role object.

Comment: @AlbertoPoljak thank you for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added Alberto Poljak's suggestions and it worked!

```py
import discord.utils 
@client.command()
async def role(ctx, * role: discord.Role):
  user = ctx.message.author
  await user.add_roles(role)
```