# How do you add roles in discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to add a role to someone but when I do the

```py
client.add_roles(member, role)
```

I have tried everything I could think of with the code it just gives me that message, I have looked at several other questions around looking for the answer but everyone says to do that command that I have tried but it wont work.

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_role('Unverified')
async def verify(ctx, nickname):
    gmember = ctx.message.author #This is the looking for the memeber
    role = discord.utils.get(gmember.server.roles, name='Guild Member')
    channel = client.get_channel(401160140864094209)
    await gmember.edit(nick=f"{nickname}")
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    r = requests.get("This is the link to the API but it shows my key and everything so not going to put it here but it works in other commands")
    #if nickname in role:
    #  await ctx.send(f"You have already verified your account.")
    if nickname.encode() in r.content:
        await channel.send(f'@here ``{nickname}`` is in the guild.')
        await client.add_roles(gmember, role)
    else:
        await gmember.kick()
```

Instance of `Bot` has no `add_roles` member `pylint` (no-member)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you assign roles with the discord.py rewrite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56451752/how-do-you-assign-roles-with-the-discord-py-rewrite)

Answer (score 0):

`await gmember.add_roles(role)`
You can read more [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.2/api.html#discord.Member)